# How can I get a Canadian visa photo at home?

Tags: photography

As in the title - I know a photo for official documents has to meet several requirements, however, I assume there has to be an easier way to do it, rather than spend hours on editing it (especially by an amateur like me).And I cannot go to a professional photography studio :(

Comment: Editing a photograph for a visa is illegal in most jurisdictions.  Such modifications can be easily detected by immigration officials, especially those countries that insist you visit their embassy so they can match the photograph to your face.

Comment: In UK at least, many supermarkets and railway stations have a photo booth that makes passport approved photos. The modern ones can email you them. Many supermarkets also have a small concession store that cuts keys, take photos, etc. It's hardly a "studio", just a bit of white or grey wall. I've tried making my own at home and found it very hard to get right.

Comment: When I need a passport/visa photo I go to a small professional place and get one for $20 or so. They know the rules well, so I think $20 is worth it to avoid the possibility of having it rejected. And for them, it's a cheap source of income, because it only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

That's super simple. There are tons of photo croppers, passport photo generators etc. Here is a random [visa photo generator](https://passport-photo.online/canada-visa-photo-35x45-mm) that looks decent.

Comment: Hi Ziomekziomek, Welcome to Lifehacks. Not to be alarmist but to note the growing use of Face Identification technology, I can think of no better way to get a database of positive Identification along with photographic likeness by a web site (as a service?) uploaded for free. Where will this data go, be stored, and be used? As it stands, "image scraping" of Facebook pages by private interest companies such as Clearview AI has become a matter of increased interest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite possible. Just use any photo cropper and make its dimension in accordance with the advised ones.

Comment: Simple cropping is clearly inadequate as the requirements for visa photographs are far more complex than mere dimensions.